# How to apply brushing on a dynamically growing dataset?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dynamically growing timeseries I need to display in a zoomable/panable chart.

Try it out here (in fact: my first jsFiddle ever :) ) :

https://jsfiddle.net/Herkules001/L12k5zwx/29/

I tried to do it the same way as described here: https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/replacing-data.html

However, each time the chart updates, the zoom and filter are lost on the focus chart. (The brush is preserved on the range chart however.)

How can I add data without resetting the views and losing the zoom?

```
var chart = dc.lineChart("#test");
var zoom = dc.lineChart("#zoom");

//d3.csv("morley.csv", function(error, experiments) {
var experiments = d3.csvParse(d3.select('pre#data').text());
  experiments.forEach(function(x) {
    x.Speed = +x.Speed;
  });

  var ndx                 = crossfilter(experiments),
      runDimension        = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Run;}),
      speedSumGroup       = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.Speed * d.Run / 1000;});

  chart
    .width(768)
    .height(400)
    .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([6,20]))
    .brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel("This is the Y Axis!")
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(speedSumGroup)
    .rangeChart(zoom);

  zoom
    .width(768)
    .height(80)
    .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([6,20]))
    .brushOn(true)
    .yAxisLabel("")
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(speedSumGroup);

    zoom.render();
    chart.render();

  var run = 21;
  setInterval(
    () => {

      var chartfilter = chart.filters();
      var zoomfilter = zoom.filters();

      chart.filter(null);
      zoom.filter(null);

      ndx.add([{Expt: 6, Run: run++, Speed: 100 + 5 * run}]);
      chart.x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([6,run]));
      zoom.x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([6,run]));

      chart.filter([chartfilter]);
      zoom.filter([zoomfilter]);

      chart.render();
      zoom.render();
    },
    1000);  

//});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, this helps so much in troubleshoting. Pro tip: "it does not work" is never a descriptive bug report. :) This mostly looks good, but I guess you want the focus chart to stay zoomed while the range chart keeps growing?

Comment: Thx Gordon for asking. Of course, yes, I want the filter be active even after new data is added like in the `replacing-data.html` sample.

Comment: I apologize for being dense - just want to improve the question. SO questions are supposed to be self-contained and descriptive, so it's best to spell out the expected and observed behavior. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, if you are just adding data, you don't need to do the complicated clearing and restoring of filters demonstrated in the example you cited.

That part is only necessary because `crossfilter.remove()` originally would remove the data that matched the current filters. An awkward interface, almost never what you want.

If you're only adding data, you don't have to worry about any of that:

```
setInterval(
() => {
  ndx.add([{Expt: 6, Run: run++, Speed: 5000 + 5 * run}]);
  chart.redraw();
  zoom.redraw();
},
5000);
```

Note that you'll get less flicker, and decent animated transitions, by using `redraw` instead of `render`. I also added [evadeDomainFilter](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.stackMixin.html#evadeDomainFilter__anchor) to avoid lines being clipped before the edge of the chart.

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/3ar4sp19/23/)

#### Removing data

If you use the predicate form of `crossfilter.remove()` you don't have to worry about saving and restoring filters:

```
  ndx.remove(d => d.Run < run-20);
```

However, this does expose other bugs in dc.js. Seems like `elasticY` does not work, similar to what's described [in this issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1538). And [you get some weird animations](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/507).

[Here's a demo with remove enabled.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/3ar4sp19/29/)

In the end, dc.js has some pretty neat features, and there is usually a way to get it to do what you want, but it sure is quirky. It's a very complicated domain and in my experience you are going to find some of these quirks in any fully featured charting library.

Update: I fixed the [replacing data example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/replacing-data.html), that one is just `ndx.remove(() => true)` now.

#### zooming issues

As Joerg pointed out in the comments,

- when the chart is not zoomed, it would be nice to have it also grow to show new data as it arrives
- the X domain was clipped or even reversed if the focus reached outside the original domain of the chart

We can address these issues by adding a [preRedraw event handler](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on__anchor). That's the ideal place to adjust the domain; for example you can implement `elasticX` manually if you need to. (As you'll see in a second, we do!)

First, a naive attempt that's easy to understand:

```
chart.on('preRedraw', () => {
  chart.elasticX(!zoom.filters().length);
});
```

We can turn `elasticX` on and off based on whether the range chart has an active filter.

This works and it's nice and simple, but why does the chart get so confused when you try to focus on a domain that wasn't in the original chart?

Welp, it records the original domain ([source](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/007e0fea30fb407bdfee19f2bdfa2335640b007e/src/coordinate-grid-mixin.js#L250a)). So that it can restore to that domain if the focus is cleared, and also to stop you from zooming or panning past the edge of the graph.

But notice from the source link above that we have an escape hatch. It records the original domain *when the X scale is set*. So, instead of setting `elasticX`, we can calculate the extent of the data, set the domain of the scale, and tell the chart that the scale is new:

```
chart.on('preRedraw', () => {
  if(!zoom.filters().length) {
    var xExtent = d3.extent(speedSumGroup.all(), kv => kv.key);
    chart.x(chart.x().domain(xExtent));
  }
});
```

[New fiddle with zooming issues fixed.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/3ar4sp19/40/)

There is still one glitch which Joerg points out: if you are moving the brush while data comes in, the brush handles occasionally will occasionally stray from the ends of the brush. In my experience, these kinds of glitches are pretty common in D3 (and dynamic charting in general), because it's difficult to think about data changing during user interaction. It probably could be fixed inside the library (perhaps an interrupted transition?) but I'm not going to get into that here.

Comment: Thanks alot Gordon, so far.  

I checked [your fork of my sample](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/3ar4sp19/23/), there still *it does not work* :) in this respect:  

* `chart` does not reflect added data (while `zoom` does)
    * can be fixed by adding `elasticX(true)` to `chart`, but then brushing has no effect any more
* brushing does not work beyond `run>20`, x-axis in `chart` never exceeds 20
* if the brush is completely beyond 20, x-axis in `chart` gets reversed
* when dragging the brush while data is added, brush handles and the grey area can eventually diverge

Comment: seems that bullet lists are not allowed in comments ... hopefully it is readable anyway...

Comment: I expect that most of these points can be fixed, but not the last one. Allowing a redraw / change of data while the brush is being moved is a tough problem, and dc.js wasn't designed for serious real-time concurrency.

Comment: okay, I've updated my answer. might be nice to make this into a library example!

Comment: Thank you Gordon!  
This works exactly as I wanted it to work.
I move on looking for the next trap :) .....